# Resume rsync transfer after failure?

Tags: partition, rsync, disk

I'm transfering the content from one smaller partition to another larger using `rsync -vacHS --progress /oldPartMountPoint/ /newPartMountPoint/`. The data is large ~1TB, I left it overnight but at the morning I found it with almost no progress. Also, the two partitions are just ISCSI devices shared from a NAS. The NAS doesn't show any disk ot network activity coming from the VM I am using to transfer the files. I know the name of the last transfered directory. Can I renew the process in some way that I only have to transfer the last of the files that have not being copied , not everything from start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is one of the least efficient scenarios for `rsync`. You have two remote filesystems, both mounted locally. This means that `rsync` cannot optimise file transfers for files that already exist on the target by sending only changed blocks. Furthermore you've specified `-c` (`--checksum`) so on restart every completed pair of source and destination files will have to be verified with a full data checksum.

The only improvement I can offer here is for you to remove `-c` from the list of options. If you don't have hard-linked files then also omit `-H` (`--hard-links`).

```
rsync -vaHS --progress /oldPartMountPoint/ /newPartMountPoint/
```

You can rerun this command as many times as you need, and it will skip previously copied files.

I'm aware this doesn't address the lack of disk or network activity on your VM; you will have to add details of that into your question if you need answers to address that issue.

Comment: Actually, I waited for couple of hours with "... sending incremental file list" and removed the -c parameter. It was instant start. About the network and disk activity, I added these details because I could not see actual transfer of large chunk of data between the VM and the NAS device, after running the command without -c everything went back to normal!